# Advantages of EAP Authenticator in EAP protocol

Tags: authentication, protocols

What is the purpose of using a EAP authenticator in the [EAP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Authentication_Protocol) ? Since underhood, the authentication procedure is between the EAP peer and the authentication server, what is the advantages of using a third actor (that is, the EAP authenticator) ?

[image]

Comment: after eap success Radius sends keys to Authenticator, client calculates same keys, and Authenticator grants access to network